# Rails 4 sorting a date field not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 models that are associated:

A User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
has_many :events
```

An Event Model

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end
```

In my Index controller and method I am listing the events for each user, and as simple as it seems, for some reason I'm not able to change the order. I have a "even_date" date field in my Event model that I am trying to sort by, created_at won't do the trick as dates can change for events as we all know.

What is best practices? Sort in the Model or Controller?

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!

 def index
   @user = User.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
   @events = @user.events.order(event_date: :desc)      
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@events = @user.events.order(events.event_date: :desc)
```

Comment: Hmm.. that blew it up with this error: `syntax error, unexpected ':' @events = @user.events.order(events.event_date: :desc) ^`

Comment: try using a string @events = @user.events.order('events.event_date desc')

Comment: the symbols may not work, because you need to specify the table that event_date belongs to.

Comment: Yeah that @events = @user.events.order('events.event_date desc') didn't do it either.. hmm scratching my head

Comment: can you post the console output when you load the page?

Comment: ``Started GET "/users/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-25 21:15:10 -0700
Processing by AdminController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  Event Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]``

Comment: Can you throw a ".all" on the end of that query?

Comment: This works fine on my machine, I can only assume there is something in "find_by_permalink" that is interfering with the query. Can you use this instead? @events = Event.where(:user_id => @user.id).order('events.event_date desc')